# No video output on GPU or MOBOTHERBOARD (pc does nothing?)

Tags: graphics-card, bios, power-supply, gpu

I have a pc from 2007, the issue is, the power LED is on, like normal, when the following cable is disconnected:

[image]

But, no GPU or BIOS VGA output.

When I connect it, the CPU fan spins, normally, but the power LED is not lightning up and still no GPU / BIOS VGA output..

How can I make the BIOS display anything on my monitor?

The motherboard model is GA-T671MG

I tried the power supply on another mobo and it works fine, I tried another power supply on this motherboard and still no video output.

I checked all cabled and I did a quick scan for scratches on the motherboard. everything looks fine.

No beep or any sound. Tried pluggin earphones into audio out and waiting for the windows sound to come. nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The three visible capacitors in the picture have expanded tops, meaning they have failed and therefore the board can't hold/control voltage properly for certain areas and components on the board.

[image: Cap Failure]

Throw that board out, it's bad.

Picture source and more info regarding expanded caps [Here](http://akroncdnr.com/services/capacitor_failure.html).

Maybe also check [this page out](http://www.ehow.com/info_8580657_causes-capacitors-bulge.html).

Comment: I think I'll try to aquire replacement condensators :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried another video card in the system to rule that out? The reason I ask is that while the capacitors on the mobo might also be bad, this sounds like a video card problem. I had a spark go from my TV to my video card, which fried the video card (though there were no visible signs), and my computer was doing about the same thing. There was no VGA BIOS POST or anything, though the lights came on and the fans were all spinning.

Comment: yeah I even tried my GPU and I tested the GPU in another PC and there it works

Comment: Sounds like techie007 has your answer then.